# Texmaker + User Command + Launching graphical editor

Tags: texmaker, editors, linux, revision-control

I'm trying to customize Texmaker to my needs. I use `git` to version my documents, so I would like to set a user command to `git-commit`. An editor should then be invoked to receive my commit message.

Normally it would call `vim`, but that's a command-line editor. When working from Texmaker, it should start a graphical editor, such as `gedit`. So I thought I'd use the command:

```
GIT_EDITOR="gedit -w -s" git-commit -a
```

Now here's the thing: It won't work as a user-command. It simply does nothing. On a hunch I put the same command in the field for DVI viewer. And lo and behold, that works as expected. The external viewer commands can open new X windows, but for some reason the user commands cannot.

I usually know my way around Linux, but I'm not sure about this one. I tried some obvious tricks, like prepending `DISPLAY=:0`, but to no avail. Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Guess: may be make Texmaker aware of `git` or `gedit` executable bin path in  `Configure Texmaker`-->`Commands`--> `Add to PATH` and then `User Command` may take into effect. Related TeXstudio Q:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112396/texstudio-texmaker-and-github