# Run commands sequentially inside TeXStudio script

Tags: macros, texstudio

I'm trying to set up a macro to set up git repo for version control, so that I don't have to resort to manual terminal commands every time. [Commit & push scripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112560) are ready and working, it's initialising a new git repo that gives me grief:

The idea is that a script will perform 4 functions:

1. Initialise a git repo at the same directory your file is saved
2. Clone a remote repo (I have a base repo with scripts/packages I want present into all tex projects I create)
3. Create a new remote repo (using [Node GH](http://nodegh.io/)) and assign it as the origin (basically re-creating the ability to fork a repo from yourself via command line)
4. Commit and push all files to the new remote repo.

Here's my code:

```
%SCRIPT
buildManager.runCommand("git init", editor.fileName());
buildManager.runCommand("gh re --new " + editor.fileName() + 
  " --type private", editor.fileName());
buildManager.runCommand("git clone https://github.com/example/example.git " 
  + editor.fileName(), editor.fileName());
buildManager.runCommand("git remote set-url origin https://github.com/example/" 
  + editor.fileName(), editor.fileName());
buildManager.runCommand("git push origin master", editor.fileName());
buildManager.runCommand("git push --all", editor.fileName())
```

The problem is I think TeXStudio doesn't perform the commands in order of appearance, which results in some commands failing (sample output at the bottom). Is there a way to define the order the commands are performed? Alternatively, can I do the same by calling a bash script (where I can definitely define the order) and pass the working dir through the macro?

---

Log output:

```
Process started: git push --all
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Process exited with error(s)    
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Process exited with error(s)
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Process exited with error(s)
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/NewProject': Permission denied
/.git: Permission denied
Process exited with error(s)
Process exited with error(s)
Process exited normally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work-around until TeXStudio allows for arguments to its `system()` command (see [Tim Hoffmann's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300892/100670) for details).

What follows works basically like this: A shell script changes the working dir to the desired path, uses Node GH to create a remote repo with the desired name and clones it to the working dir. The working dir and repo name are passed to the script as arguments by two input dialogs.

```
%SCRIPT
choisedialog = UniversalInputDialog()
choisedialog.setWindowTitle("Repo Name")
choisedialog.add(editor.fileName(), "New Repository:", "name")
if (choisedialog.exec() != null) {
    dialog = new UniversalInputDialog()
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Working Dir")
    dialog.add(editor.fileName(), "Dir path:", "dir")
    if (dialog.exec() != null) {
        repoName = choisedialog.get("name")
        workDir = dialog.get("dir")
        system("sh /Users/nikko/git/scripts/createRepo.sh " + repoName + " \"" + workDir + "\"")
        }
}
```

createRepo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#make sure you clone the generic repo on an empty folder,
#otherwise git will complain.

file="$1"
dir="$2"

cd "$dir"
gh re --new "$file" --type private  \
&& git clone https://github.com/user/genericRepoName.git . \
&& git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/"$file".git \
&& git push origin master  \
&& git push --all
```

Answer (score 3):

`buildmanager.runCommand()` does not wait for the termination of the command. If you need that control, you should use `system()` instead. It returns a process object which you then can control (for details see [the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)).

In your particular case, it would still be a bit tedious because you want to have the command executed in the directory of the file. As of now (TXS 2.10.8) the working directory of `system()` is the working directory of TeXstudio. So you either have to start TeXstudio from the shell in the desired directory or you have to wrap the git call in a shell script that changes the directory first.

Future releases will allow an optional second argument to `system()` for providing a working directory.

```
filename = editor.fileName()
workdir = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("/"))
proc = system("git init", workdir)
proc.waitForFinished()
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll look forward to the additional arguments in future releases. I did end up enclosing it in a shell script in the end, passing two arguments from input dialogs for file name and working dir. I'll post the workaround below as an answer, just for reference.