# TeXstudio and GitHub

Tags: texstudio, git

I've seen this link: [TeXstudio / TeXmaker and GitHub](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112396/texstudio-texmaker-and-github) which is exactly what I want but I do have an issue:

When I use the scripts they always fail because I cannot put my username and password from git in there... Does someone know how to do it?

Thank you very much, community!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) I don't use git, but can't get store your username and password in its configuration like subversion does?

Comment: Use [`ssh`](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) and copy your public key to your GitHub profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by making:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

And then making a push. After that my pc doesn't require any more info about my username and password so git push works directly without any input.

More info: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/